# Is there a step by step tutorial on how to use EtherDelta exchange?

Tags: etherdelta

Totally new to using the etherdelta exchange. Is there a well written up step by step tutorial on how to use etherdelta exchange to make a trade?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this in November 2016, so it might be a bit out of date

https://medium.com/@dontravlos/etherdelta-the-best-thing-since-596ad87a26c?source=linkShare-87790377ee47-1509391020

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of videos in [etherdelta's channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCkUTWdqHjFUfC98gFUsNuzg) which explains how etherdelta works and well as how to trade in etherdelta using metamask (which is recommended) though you can do without one too.